# How do I configure the login form to redirect to a specific url?

Tags: django

**Goal**

When the user visits `http://myserver/accounts/login/?next=/sentry`, it should prompt for login credentials, then redirect to `/sentry`. This is the behavior if you are using the `login_required` decorator. I am not using that decorator.

**Symptom**

Currently, after a successful login, it is redirecting to `/accounts/profile` even though the `next` query param is provided.

**Question**

1. Where do I override the default redirect url `/accounts/profile` ?
2. Why is passing `next` not enough ?

Comment: You could help here by providing some of your urls.py file, and the template you're using.

Answer (score 2):

To override the default redirect target, set the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` setting, which defaults to `/accounts/profile`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL

I can't answer the other part of the question without knowing how you are logging the user in. Are you using your own view and the `login()` function? In that case you need to handle the `next` parameter yourself.

If you are using the generic view, you can pass the `redirect_field_name` parameter, which should default to "next".

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can override the default redirect URL by setting `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in settings.py.

In answer to the second part of your question - you'll need to make sure there is a hidden input in the form in your login template which contains `next`. What does your template look like? It needs to contain something like this:

```
<form method='post'>{% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
  <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="big_button">
</form>
```

If you have passed `redirect_field_name` as a parameter to the login view, then you'll need that as the name of the input rather than `next`.